# Actualizar una cuenta en Laravel

Tags: php, laravel

Quiero actualizar los datos de una cuenta, busco la cuenta con el id en el edit:

```
public function edit($id)
    {
        $cuenta = Cuenta::find($id);
        return view('cuentas.edit', compact('cuenta'));
    }
```

y la funcion de update que recibe los valores de la vista que es un formulario y busco el ide que concuerde con el que fue mandado y guardo los nuevos datos en los campos:

```
public function update(Request $request, $id)
    {
        $nuevoNombre = $request->input('Nombre');
        $nuevoDescripcion = $request->input('Descripcion');
        $nuevoInteres = $request->input('Interes');
        $cuenta = Cuenta::find($id);
        $cuenta ->name = $nuevoNombre;
        $cuenta ->descripcion = $nuevoDescripcion;
        $cuenta ->interes = $nuevoInteres;
        $cuenta->save;
        return  $cuenta;
    }
```

eso es lo que esta en el controlador de la cuenta
la vista que manejo para ver y actualizar que es un formulario uso el emtodo put que dice la pagina de Laravel:

```
@extends('layouts.app')
@section('title', 'Actualizar Cuenta')

@section('content')
  <div class="conatainer">
      <form class=class="form-group" action="/cuentas/{{$cuenta->id}}" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        @method('PUT')
        @csrf
        <div class="form-group">
          <label for="">Nombre de Cuenta</label>
          <input type="text" name="Nombre" value="{{$cuenta->name}}" class="form-control">
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
          <label for="">Descripcion de Cuenta</label>
          <input type="text" name="Descripcion" value="{{$cuenta->descripcion}}" class="form-control">
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
          <label for="">Interes</label>
          <input type="text" name="Interes" value="{{$cuenta->interes}}" class="form-control">
        </div>
      <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Actualizar</button>
      </form>
    </div>
@endsection
```

usando el modo de protected en el modelo de la cuenta:

```
class Cuenta extends Model
{
    protected $fillable = ['name', 'descripcion', 'interes'];
}
```

supuestamente cuando mando el return de la variable cuenta me manda como deberia ser que quede con los nuevos datos que le estoy dando pero cuando vuelvo a recarga la pagina para ver los detalles siguen siendo los detalles anteriores sin que se actualizen, como podria solucionar eso y que se pueda actualizar los datos de la cuenta.

Comment: Parece que la actualización se realiza correctamente ¿Has mirado la base de datos? El problema parece ser que update no te devuelve una vista, entonces seguirías viendo los datos de la anterior, tendrías que hacer un `return view('cuentas.edit', compact('cuenta'));` al final del `update()`

Comment: Para que te guarde los datos debes llamar al metodo `save()`  tu estas llamando a una propiedad: `$cuenta->save;`  **Te faltan los paréntesis**: `$cuenta->save();`

Comment: Muchas gracias no me fije en ese pequeño detale y busque el error en todos lados menos ese.

Comment: @wilmer me alegro que lo solucionaras. Te dejo una respuesta. Un saludo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para que Laravel ejecute la consulta y guarde los datos debes llamar al método `save()`  en ti código estás llamando a una propiedad `$cuenta->save;` en lugar de llamar al método `$cuenta->save();` con los paréntesis.

Puedes revisar la documentación aquí: https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/eloquent#updates

Answer (score 0):

Con esto te serviría:

```
public function update(Request $request, $id)
{
    $nuevoNombre = $request->input('Nombre');
    $nuevoDescripcion = $request->input('Descripcion');
    $nuevoInteres = $request->input('Interes');
    $cuenta = Cuenta::where('id', '=', $id)->update(
    [
        'name' => $nuevoNombre,
        'descripcion' => $nuevoDescripcion,
        'interes' => $nuevoInteres,
    ]);


}
```

Además tienes: `$cuenta->save;` // Aqui save parece ser un campo de $user.! | 
es : `$cuenta->save();` // como función